# CSS / bxSlider: How to avoid that Images are overlapping parent div

Tags: jquery, css, image, bxslider

I am using the plugin bxslider (http://bxslider.com/) which in general works great.

My only issue is that the plugin comes with a set shadow of 5px for its viewport so if I am using it inside a div with a colored border on the div it always overlaps that border - the smaller the screen the more obvious the overlap.

Is there an exact way in CSS to override this (exact because it needs to work on small screens / mobiles as well) ?

**Firebug shows me the following default CSS that is used for the viewport:**

```
.bx-viewport {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fff;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ccc;
    left: -5px;
    transform: translateZ(0px);
}
```

I tried the following which resolves the issue for the left border but then it's overlapping the right border:

```
.bx-viewport {
    left:3px !important;
    padding-right:3px !important;
}
```

**Update:** It works when I set the width of the inner div to 99% but that only covers the larger screens, on mobile the 1% difference is not enough - that's why I am trying to find an exact workaround. Also, the issue is only for IE 8 as in newer browsers the CSS calc function works great ( `width:calc(100% - 9px) !important;` ).

Comment: can you provide your code in jsfiddle

Comment: Unfortunately not but in this case I think it is the same as any div inside another div where the inner div uses the above CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I wrong in assuming that you could simply use:

```
box-shadow: none !important
```

I can't imagine a situation where that wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks ! That worked. I thought I could keep the border of the inner div but it's ok this way.